# antlr 4.2.2 output to console warning (157)

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I downloaded latest release of ANTLR - 4.2.2 (antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar)
When I use it to generate parsers for grammar file Java.g4 it prints me some warnings like:
"Java.g4:525:16: rule 'expression' contains an 'assoc' terminal option in an unrecognized location"

Files was generated but didn't compile

Previous version works fine.

Whats wrong?

Comment: This problem (with the `Java.g4` file that comes with the source code zip file for the book [The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference/) (The Pragmatic Bookshelf, January 2013)) persists, amazingly enough, deep into 2022. There are also pretty ugly lines in the example code and deprecation warnings. That book needs a "revised edition".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `<assoc>` should now be moved left of the "expression".

It must be placed always right to the surrounding `|`:

Look here: https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Left-recursive+rules

```
 ...
 |   expression '&&' expression
    |   expression '||' expression
    |   expression '?' expression ':' expression
    |<assoc=right>   expression
        (   '='
        |   '+='
        |   '-='
        |   '*='
        |   '/='
        |   '&='
        |   '|='
        |   '^='
        |   '>>='
        |   '>>>='
        |   '<<='
        |   '%='
        )
        expression
```

Comment: and how do you get access to "theantlrguy" ?

Comment: @WeaponX seems it is no longer public

Comment: Maybe it can now be found on GitHub. https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/left-recursion.md

Comment: Confirmed. Search for assoc on this page