# C# ANTLR4 right-associative warning

Tags: c#, antlr4

Given my simple grammar in the C# build target:

```
grammar Expr;

prog: stmt+ EOF;
stmt: expr NEWLINE+;

expr:
    expr '^' <assoc=right> expr # Power
|   expr ('*'|'/') expr         # Mult
|   expr ('+'|'-') expr         # Add
|   REAL                        # Real
|   '(' expr ')'                # Paren
;

NEWLINE : '\r\n';
REAL     : [0-9]+'.'[0-9]+ ;
```

I continue to get a C# compiler warning stating that "Warning   1   rule 'expr' contains an 'assoc' terminal option in an unrecognized location"

Can anyone suggest where I'm supposed to indicate right-associativity for exponentials?  This is the way I've seen it done in numerous examples.

Comment: Perhaps this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359363/antlr-4-2-2-output-to-console-warning-157/23359897

Comment: Yes, works perfectly and tests perfectly.  Thank you.   Now, being new to this site, how do I mark help as the answer?  ;)

Comment: Well, it was not an answer but a clue to resolver your problem.  You could add the answer yourself to help other people.  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is placing the tag hint to the **left** of the rule, not right after the operator as I've seen in many examples:

```
expr:
<assoc=right> expr '^'  expr    # Power
|   expr ('*'|'/') expr         # Mult
...
;
```

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/left-recursion.md